# C, clock function return only 0.00000

Tags: c

When i run this code, it print everytime 0.000000 instead of something plausible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define n 10

void ordinaVett(int v[], int elem){

    clock_t inizio, fine;
    double tempo;
    int i, j, x, posmin, tmp;
    printf("\n\nOrdinamento vettore di %d elementi per %d volte: \n", elem, n);
    printf("Sele-sort:\n");
    for(x = 0; x < n; x++){ 
        inizio = clock();
        //Ordinamento con Sele-sort         
        for(i = 0; i < elem - 1; i++){
            posmin = i;
            for(j = i + 1; j < elem; j++){
                if(v[j] < v[posmin])
                posmin = j;
            }
            if(posmin != i){
                tmp = v[i];
                v[i] = v[posmin];
                v[posmin] = tmp;
            }
        }
        fine = clock();
        //Visualizzazione vettore
        for(i = 0; i < elem; i++){
            printf("%d |", v[i]);
        }
        tempo = (double)(fine - inizio)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("   Tempo: %f\n", tempo);
    }
}

int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));

    int elementi = 20, i;
    int v[elementi];

    printf("Creazione vettore 20 elementi: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < elementi; i++)
    {
        v[i] = rand() % 1001;
        printf("%d |", v[i]);
    }
    ordinaVett(v, elementi);

}
```

What should I do for be able to see a normal output?
Thanks!

some words are in Italian so: tempo is time, ordinaVett is sortArray, inizio is start and fine is end.

Comment: don't you want to initialise `inizio` outside the loop? You're setting it in the loop so maybe each iteration is too fast for your clock to show any value?

Comment: Instead of describing the Italian names (of which the meaning I could guess, by the way), would be better to rename them to English directly. Best: only use English variable names in all your code right from the start...

Comment: If you have access to POSIX functionality, try [clock_gettime()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) instead.

Comment: You just need to load that function. See https://ideone.com/w5ksVn it prints 0.000001. For 1000 elements it prints Tempo: 0.001308

Comment: On what basis do you judge the result implausible?  For example, are you comparing with some other estimate of the time elapsed for each sorting run?  Although we know that the sorting takes time, it might take less time than the actual resolution of the `clock()` function.

Comment: I don't follow you, @Hedgehog.  In what sense are you supposing that the OP's program could compile or run at all without "load[ing]" any function it uses?

Comment: @JohnBollinger
 "load" means give more work to do

Comment: ... and it can mean a lot of other things, too, @Hedgehog.  Thank you for clarifying.  I agree that increasing the amount of work performed in the interval being timed is an excellent way to try to observe nonzero timings.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am sorry, did not mean to confuse. You are right, this word has many meanings.

Comment: Use `"%e"` or `"%g"`.  They are more informative than `"%f"`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind, I realized that a CPU is too fast and a double variable couldn't hold a so simple number. This's for sure a pretty dumb exercize to put on a school book.

Comment: The problem is not with `double`, which can hold extremely tiny numbers -- much, much smaller than the fraction of a second consumed by a single CPU cycle.  However, it may well be that the CPU performs the work you're giving it faster than finite time between two ticks of the `clock()`, so that your `inizio` and `fine` always come out equal for the (apparently small) amount of work you're doing..